# Infinite Product of (1-x)^ib, as x approaches 1

Tags: infinite-product

Is there a simple form to this product?

$\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-\frac{i.b}{n})$

I know for sure that the gamma function relates to it somehow and it could be represented as a binomial series $1-ib+\frac{ib(ib-1)}{2!}-\frac{ib(ib-1)(ib-2)}{3!}...$, but I'm looking for gamma related identities.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn’t $(1-x)^{i b}$ different from $\left(1+\frac{ib}n\right)$?

Comment: Your question does not match your title.

Comment: Dan, Expand the function in the title and simply. They're the same.

Comment: Tyma, no they're the same when x=1